# How can i stop default nopCommerce SearchBox Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have developed one custom plugin in a Nopcommerce.

In which I want to display search box from my plugin, how it can be possible?

There is no any route defined for Search Box action method. It is directly invoked from `Header.cshtml` page by below code:

```
@Html.Action("Search Box", "Catalog")
```

In which create Search Box Method same as default nopcommerce in my plugin, but i want to call my plugin Search Box Method and stop call default nopCommerce searchBox method.

So, how it can be possible?

Comment: *There is no any route defined for Search Box action method. It is directly invoked from Header.cshtml* Yes, absolutely right.

Comment: The best way is to override `SearchBox.cshtml` view using `PluginViewEngine` from your plugin and call your method using ajax on search button click